# jQuery returns "undefined" trying to find href

Tags: jquery, href, undefined, attr

I'm trying to wrap this into a function:

```
//Entire Div Clickable
function clickableDiv(){
window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
return false;
}
```

and then call it by:

```
$("div.promo1").click(function(){
clickableDiv();
});
```

But it returns a url of: www.mywebsite.com/undefined

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `<div class="promo1"> 
<p>Some text</p> 
<h4><a href="/link/">Learn more &#187;</a></h4> 
</div><!--end promo1--> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clickableDiv(div) {
    window.location = $(div).find("a").attr("href");
}

$("div.promo1").click(function() {
    clickableDiv(this);
});
```

You have to pass the reference to the DIV into the `clickableDiv` function.

---

**Update:** Alternative solution:

```
function clickableDiv() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
}

$("div.promo1").click(clickableDiv);
```

Comment: Yea, I'd like to wrap it into a function so I can use it multiple times throughout the site and save on the file size.

Comment: @Yahreen I've updated my answer with an alternative solution. Consider it.

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that you're calling `clickableDiv` normally, rather than binding it to an event.  You are running it from an event handler, rather than setting it **as** the event handler.  This means that `this` is not set to the element.

You should set the function as the event handler instead.

```
$("div.promo1").click(clickableDiv);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to wrap it into a function so I can use it multiple times throughout the site and save on the file size. Is that possible?

Comment: @Yahreen I'm not sure what you mean, but Sime's answer looks like it's sorted you. I wouldn't worry too much about file size though.  If it's too big, you'll get much more from a minifier than you would from little tweaks like this.#